# Run macro on incoming email when offline

Tags: vba, outlook

I implemented a "do something with every new email in folder xyz" based on tutorials [here](https://www.slipstick.com/developer/itemadd-macro/) and [here](https://www.slipstick.com/developer/processing-incoming-e-mails-with-macros/) (ItemAdd method).

I want this to run when I am **not online**. Is there a solution for this typical corporate situation, where I have no access to the Outlook server?

My fallback solution is not turning off my laptop overnight.

```
Option Explicit

Private objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
Private WithEvents objNewMailItems As Outlook.Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
Dim objMyInbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Set objNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set objMyInbox = objNS.Folders("inbox@host.com").Folders("Inbox")
Set objNewMailItems = objMyInbox.Items
Set objMyInbox = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub objNewMailItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
'Ensure we are only working with e-mail items
If Item.Class <> olMail Then Exit Sub
'do something here with the incoming email
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes and No, but mainly (in your case) No.  A macro is a program.  It, like all programs, cannot run on a computer which is turned off.  In order to do what you want you will need it to run on the Exchange (or similar) server which is not turned off.  And you will need high-level permissions to do that.

Comment: Well, can your coffee machine brew a coffee if it is turned off? • That would need to be performed at best at the mail server itself. Ask the guys in your company that are responsible for your mail server. They can assist you.

Comment: My first thought is why do you want to do this?  Do you get so many emails overnight that there is a long delay while they are processed when you switch on in the morning?  Are there overnight emails that **must** be processed before you arrive in the morning?  If the former, I would not expect your server guys to care.  Start Outlook then go make yourself a coffee or find something else to do.  If the latter, this is important to your employer.  Perhaps the server guys will agree.  If not report it up your management chain to someone who has the authority to say “do it”.

Answer (score 1):

I am 7 months late and probably your problem has been solved by now I guess.
This is for more people like me who had to struggle so much to solve this. Yet it has a simple solution.
I have been facing this kind of a problem for a few days now. The only thing I count figure out to do is not actually making the macro work in offline mode, but rather process the unread emails on application startup and mark them as read.
I know it is not exactly the solution you were looking for but it might be worth a try.
Helps with not having to turn on your laptop overnight everyday :P

You don't even need to change anything in references.

```
Public WithEvents InboxItems As Outlook.Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()

Dim olApp As Object
Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

Dim olNS As Object
Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

Dim Inbox As Object
Set Inbox = olNS.Folders("dummy.dummy@dummy.com").Folders("Inbox")                     'can also change it to any custom folder you want

Dim olMail As Object
Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

Set InboxItems = Inbox.Items

Dim Item As Object

'Process Items that were not processed because you were offline
For Each Item In InboxItems.Restrict("[UnRead] = True")
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    Debug.Print Item.Subject         'Do anything you want

    Item.UnRead = False
    Next
    Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
    Resume Next
    Exit Sub

End Sub

Private Sub InboxItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
Debug.Print Item.Subject         'Do anything you want

Item.UnRead = False
Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
MsgBox "Error!"
Item.UnRead = False
Exit Sub

End Sub
```